# Bootstrap modal video player with thumbnail

Tags: video, bootstrap-modal

I created a video gallery on a website. Where a user can click on a photo and a modal open .Inside modal there is a video player . Here is the code:

```
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#<?php echo $row['title'] ?>"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="" ></a>
    <p style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></p>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 60%;height=520;padding: -10px;">
       <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
             Close
               </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

       <video width="100%" height="520" controls>
        <source src="admin/<?php echo $row['video_path'] ?>"
                                              type="video/mp4">

       Your browser does not support the video tag.
             </video>
                   </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

Now I want to keep video's thumbnail in the place of image.how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either separately generate thumbnails for each video and then use them exactly as you have the images above, or you can just have your gallery be a gallery of videos and use the HTML5 video tag as you are doing above to show the thumbnail and display the video when the user starts it.

To show the first frame as a thumbnail with the video tag just preload the metadata:

```html
<video controls="controls" preload="metadata">
  <source src="yourVideoPath" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```